# How to implement a dynamic background on ActionBar like 7x7?

Tags: android, background, android-actionbar

If you have ever played 7x7 you've surely noticed the ActionBar changing his background progressively with your points until a new level is reached.

I really like the effect and I was thinking to use it somewhere. Do you have any clue on how implement it?

I'm not sure if it could be achieved drawing a Rect over it, any help?

Thanks in advance

[image: 7x7 ActionBar]

Comment: did you read this ? http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/11/27/actionbar-on-the-move/

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice article. I will try to use it to reach the goal. : )

Answer (score 2):

This is my game! I actually made a custom Action Bar that was transparent and added the level progress bar underneath it.

If you wanted to use the default Action Bar, you could probably do the same with [windowActionBarOverlay](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowActionBarOverlay).

Comment: Ahahaha, cool! Thanks for your answer! It will be great to have a little snippet.. am I asking too much? Btw compliments for the game, It's so simple and addictive! ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have any code that I can post. Sorry!

Comment: No problem. I will give you a +1 for your help. :)